# ColorRamp on glass animation bug?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, glass

I used in one of my projects a *Color Ramp* on glass texture.

At first all seems to be perfect at the beginning of the animation, but at the middle the *Color Ramp* on the middle streaks and smallest streaks is going to turn white for a few frames and normal and white etc.

Did I do anything wrong, or is it a bug?

[image: Normal Colorramp]

[image: White streas but the biggest middle one is constant normal]